# Issue installing Savon gem on Red Hat Enterprise server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-services, libxml2, savon

I am using webservices to communicate to an ERP from ruby on rails application using `Savon`.
I was able to install Savon gem on my local fedora machine. But I am not able to install it on Production server.
It gives following error :-

```
ERROR:  Error installing savon:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for libxml/parser.h... no
-----
libxml2 is missing.  please visit http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html for help with installing dependencies.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.
```

Tried to reinstall `libxml2` but that also gave error.
Can anyone help me to debug this issue?

Thanks In Advance.....

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is right there in the error message:

> libxml2 is missing. please visit http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html
>   for help with installing dependencies.

They even provide a Red Hat guide.